# Divergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} [ye^{1/(2y)}]^{-1}\text{ d}y$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

This came up on a probability exam I took.

> Show that  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{ye^{1/(2y)}}\text{ d}y$$ is
>   divergent.

In the language of probability, suppose $Y$ has pdf $\dfrac{1}{2y^2}e^{-1/(2y)}$ for $y > 0$. Show that $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ does not exist.

When I saw this question, integration by parts doesn't work too well, nor could I think of an integral for comparison. I still look at this question and am unsure how to deal particularly with the $e^{-1/(2y)}$.

This does not look like a straight substitution would work either, as we would need a $y^2$ term, rather than just a $y$ term.

Answers should not use anything more than what is taught at a multivariate calculus background (real analysis, outside of inequalities, should be unnecessary).

Comment: The easiest way is to use a simple lower bound on the function. You can transform this into an exponential integral (see wikipedia) with the substitution $u = -1/2y$, so I doubt there's a closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the integrand when $y\to \infty$.

Change variable $y=\frac{1}{2 x}$ so $$I=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2 y}}}{y}\,dy=-\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$$ When $x$ is small $$\frac{e^{-x}}{x}=\frac{1}{x}-1+\frac{x}{2}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ $$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\approx \log (x)-x+\frac{x^2}{4}+O\left(x^3\right)$$

**Edit**

In fact, using special functions,  $$I=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2 y}}}{y}\,dy=-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2 y}\right)$$ where appears [the exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). So, $$J=\int_0^a\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2 y}}}{y}\,dy=\Gamma \left(0,\frac{1}{2 a}\right)$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function. For large values of $a$, the asymptotics is $$J=\log (a)-\gamma +\log (2)+\frac{1}{2
   a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

As $y\to \infty$, $e^{1/2y} \to 1$.  So for some number $N$, $y>N$ assures us that $e^{1/2y} > 1/2.$  Then

$$\int_1^{\infty} \geq \int_N^{\infty} \geq \int_N^{\infty} \frac{1}{2y} \; dy $$ which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

As $y\to\infty$, we have asymptotically
$$
\frac1ye^{-\frac1{2y}}=\frac1y-\frac1{2y^2}+O\left(\frac1{y^3}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac1ye^{-\frac1{2y}}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
is divergent since
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac1y\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
is divergent and 
$$
\int_1^\infty\left(-\frac1{2y^2}+O\left(\frac1{y^3}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

First we look at $f(y) = y \cdot e^{\frac{1}{2y}}$. Then $\int_0^\infty f(y)\mathrm{d}y <\infty$ (in the language of probability; we know the expected value of expontential decay probability is finite).

Next, note that $$\int_0^\infty 1 = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{f}}{\sqrt{f}} \leq \left(\int_0^\infty f\right)^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\int_0^\infty f^{-1}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$ By holder inequality.
Since the left-hand side is $\infty$, the right-hand side must also be $\infty$. Now, we know $\int_0^\infty f(y)\mathrm{d}y <\infty$, and so we conclude $\int_0^\infty f^{-1}(y)\mathrm{d}y =\infty$